# How to learn Mathematics for Machine Learning?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, machine-learning

**tl;dr**
Is the following path (with the following books) the correct way to learn Mathematics for Machine Learning?
0. Pre-algebra (Pre-Algebra Essentials For Dummies by Mark Zegarelli, Krista Fanning)

1. College Algebra (Schaum’s Outline of College Algebra by Robert E. Moyer, Murray R. Spiegel)
2. Pre-calculus (Schaum’s Outline of Precalculus by Fred Safier)
3. Calculus (Schaums Outline of Calculus by Frank Ayres, Elliott Mendelson)
4. Differential Equations (Schaum’s Outline of Differential Equations by Richard Bronson, Gabriel B. Costa)
5. Discrete Mathematical Structures (Schaums Outline of Discrete Mathematics by Seymour Lipschutz, Marc Lipson)
6. Linear Algebra (Introduction to Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang)
7. Statistics and Probability (Practical Statistics for Data Scientists 50+ Essential Concepts Using R and Python by Peter Bruce, Andrew Bruce, Peter Gedeck)

Here's the lengthier version of my query. I was never bad with studies, however, I got bad grades and just passed my college because of some personal issues. I have been working since then in jobs which didn't require much mathematics.

I have switched careers now and I am working as a Machine Learning Engineer now. I did a course in Machine Learning but skipped the mathematics part. I want to study mathematics now, not just because it is required at work, but because I was always fascinated by mathematics. The issue is, I put in 60 hours a week in office. I take out time to study after work. So I want to know if these books would actually help me understand the mathematics behind Machine Learning, or these will not cover it? Thank you for reading through this, any suggestion/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend this link: https://mathblog.com/mathematics-books/
Except for differential equations, the branches of mathematics you are focusing on seem right, but there are better books out there for some of the topics

Comment: Thank you for the link. I agree, there are definitely better books. I would always prefer Spivak over For Dummies books. However, I specifically chose these because of the time constraint. Do you think I would have to devout considerably more amount of time if I switched from For Dummies series to these other books?

Comment: Well, that depends entirely upon you. Different people learn in different ways. Sometimes an explanation may make sense to me but not to you and vice versa. When I was learning this stuff, I sometimes had to skim through several books and/or lectures before a concept "clicked".
Also, please look at KhanAcademy for the basics. He's really good at breaking things down for people who are not used to mathematical notation and proofs (check the Wikipedia article for mathematical maturity. If that doesn't apply to you, definitely start with Khan).

Comment: You are right. I cannot focus on time, rather I should focus on the learning. I wouldn't say I am mathematically challenged, I finished the Pre-algebra book within 2 days. I just need to give it time. Thank you so much for taking the time out to reply to this. Highly appreciate it.

Comment: I would drop 4 and 5.

Comment: @Elmex80s: Correct me if I am wrong, partial differentiation and differential equations are the same. Because there are number of concepts in ML that requires partial differentiation, including something as basic as SGD.

Comment: Also, I chose 5 because of Set Theory. Please suggest.

Comment: The kind of partial differentiation done in ML has little to do with partial differential equations. Differential equations and differentiation are not synonymous. DEs are equations in which the function is the unknown while the kind if differentiation in ML assumes that the form of the function is already known. You only need calculus for the latter

Answer (score 1):

I would probably switch 'Differential Equations' with a book on optimization theory. I haven't read any of the books you mention, but judging from the titles they seem to be highly relevant.

I would also like to recommend the following (free) book, which seems to be just what you are looking for. Mathematics for Machine Learning.
https://mml-book.github.io/

It covers a lot of the topics you mention and it also has a section in every chapter with recommended further readings.

Comment: I did check out this book. However, since my knowledge of mathematics is still rudimentary, I was a little taken aback by the notations in this book. Which is why I thought it best to start off at the beginning. What do you think/suggest?

Comment: Oh, right. In that case you are definitely on the right track.

It's probably still useful to keep it as a reference, so when you start reading up on e.g. Linear Algebra you can use the MML book as a guide to see what topics you should focus on. (For Linear Algebra it will probably be the whole book).

The authors of MML present it as a prerequisite for reading the more advanced books (such as 'Elements of Statistical Learning') so it's not going to be an exhaustive list. Just something to keep in mind!

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with the literature, but I also recommend the book 'Introduction to Statistical Learning', which isn't focused on the technical details, but more on the practical applications of machine learning. I think this will help you identify important topics from the more basic, theoretical books.

It can also be downloaded for free, (since they will release a new version soon, which I am super excited about!)  
https://www.statlearning.com/

Comment: I have been through Hands-on ML by Geron. I understood about 75% of the mathematical explanation given there. Like, if you ask me how a lasso and a ridge regression works (not just the code but the underlying mathematics), I would be ale to give you a detailed explanation. But topics like SVM are still out of reach for me. I'll be able to create a model, but not know how it works.

Comment: Oh, I do have a copy of Intro to Statistical Learning. It looks great, very lucid explanation.

Comment: All right, that's good! With machine learning it is possible to do something useful without understanding all the details, but by understanding how the models work and what they do, you will become more competent. You'll know what you can and can't do to fix a model that isn't performing that great for instance. Definitely worth spending some time learning the theory!